# extract list pattern from list of list in python

Tags: python, list, nested

I have a list of the form -

```
a_list = [[1, [2, 3, 4]], [2, [3, 4]], [3, [4]]]
```

I want to convert it to the form  -

```
b_list = [[1,2],[1,3],[1,4],[2,3],[2,4],[3,4]]
```

Using the list comprehension, I have tried with below code

```
for lst in tup:
    for lst1 in tup[1]:
        tup2 = [lst[0],lst1]
```

and getting (which is wrong)-

```
tup2 = [3, [3, 4]]
```

Please help, Thanks in advance

Comment: What is happening today? Is it the international *list-of-lists day*?

Comment: Might be worthwhile to make a list of list-of-lists questions.

Comment: @Ev.Kounis Haha!!! Maybe...Can you help me??

Comment: let's make a "print numbers as triangle" tag as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple to do with a list comprehension:

```
a_list = [[1, [2, 3, 4]], [2, [3, 4]], [3, [4]]]

b_list = [[x,y] for [x,b] in a_list for y in b]

print(b_list)
```

result:

```
[[1, 2], [1, 3], [1, 4], [2, 3], [2, 4], [3, 4]]
```

using `[x,b]` unpacks the items into `x` as number and `b` as your list. Loop through elements of `b` and build the couples, flat-style.

Answer (score -1):

You could try something like this , no matter how many int are there :

```
for sub_list in b:
    for items in sub_list:
        if isinstance(items, list):
            track = sub_list.index(items)
            first = sub_list[:track]
            second = sub_list[track:][0]
            import itertools

            print([list(k) for k in itertools.product(first, second)])
```

test case:

```
b = [[1, [2, 3, 4]], [2, [3, 4]], [3, [4]]]
```

output:

```
[[1, 2], [1, 3], [1, 4]]
[[2, 3], [2, 4]]
[[3, 4]]
```

test case 2:

```
b=[[1,2,[2, 3, 4]], [2,3,5,6 ,[3, 4]], [3, [4]]]
```

output:

```
[[1, 2], [1, 3], [1, 4], [2, 2], [2, 3], [2, 4]]
[[2, 3], [2, 4], [3, 3], [3, 4], [5, 3], [5, 4], [6, 3], [6, 4]]
[[3, 4]]
```

Comment: This does a ton of convoluted, unnecessary extra work and doesn't even produce the `b_list` the questioner wanted.

Comment: @user2357112 thanks for putting effort in  downvote. , just put all sublist in a list and you will get that b_list.  Bdw why are you tracking my questions?